# Display content when changing a user profile custom field using ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, userid, acfpro

I have created a ACF field group which displays inside a Wordpress user profile. Within that field group is a simple dropdown field with 4 options. I am trying to create a shortcode where by an admin can select one of these options inside a users profile. Once they do this, a button/link/text would appear on a specific page that only the user would see once logged in.

Eg. If an admin selects the 'Approved' option, then the user would see some text on the front end saying 'You're approved'. Here is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working.

```php
add_shortcode('pdf-capa-button', 'capa_btn');

function capa_btn() {   
    
   $user_id = get_current_user_id();
   $variable = get_field('capa_statut', "user_{$id}");      
   $content = '';
    
   if($variable == "CAPA Approved") {
      $content .=  '<p>You are approved!</p>';  
   }
   return $content;
}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? The code doesn't seem to be throwing any errors but nonetheless, the shortcode isn't generating any content on the front end. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just double-checking: is this a copy-paste of your code? Because `$id` is not the same variable you're assigning the user id to... that would be `$user_id`, right?

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean so the $variable should be

$variable = get_field('capa_statut', "user_".$user_id);   instead

Comment: That's correct, Adam.  Does that solve your problem?

Comment: It has. Thank you both. Can't believe I missed that one